# Tableview selection stored to Core Data entity

Tags: swift, core-data

I am currently building an app that presents the user with a list of items to select from. I want those selections to store to core data because it will be used in multiple different tableviews.

Right now I have the core data model setup to receive a boolean for the selection as well as the quantity of that selection. I am a little lost on how to do this as all the references I can find are pre swift and swift is the only language I read at the moment.

To give a little more insight I have an entity setup with a boolean attribute and an integer attribute to determine the selection and quantity of that selection.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards
    let indexPath = cardsListed.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let currentCell = cardsListed.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell?
    DeckCards.setValue(true, forKey: "cardsSelected")
    managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
}
```

I am considering using a checkmark to show which items are going to be saved to the user....as matter of a fact this is the way I want to go it doesn't change much in that I still can't find swift examples of doing this.
Attached below is a image of my core data model for better understanding:
[[image: core data model][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XO0r.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the edit Tom! Sorry my editing skills are bad I should be more formal than I usually am with my gaming buds.

Comment: Anyone who can help me save the users selections from the tableview permanently to core data in anyway boolean or otherwise would be an awesome amount of  help.

Comment: Can you explain your model some more?  By the looks, your table view is populated with Cards objects using an FRC, but you are setting the boolean attribute on a different object (DeckCards).  What entity type is DeckCards, and how is it related to Cards?

Comment: DeckCards is a entity that contains 2 attributes a cardSelection attribute which is a boolean and a cardQuantity attribute which is a integer. It is related to the Card entity which contains the objects that are the selection the user can choose from in a Many To One Relationship. To make things easy to understand I have attached a screenshot of my core data model.

Comment: I edited my initial post to include a image plus the direction I am thinking of heading with this.

Comment: Sorry, more questions: is the relationship between the Cards and DeckCards already set, or are you making that relationship when the user selects the relevant row?  For the DeckCards entity, does the cardsSelected attribute represent "the user has/has not selected the cards for this DeckCard entity" or does it represent "the user has selected this particular card for this DeckCard"?  Likewise, is numberSelected "the total number of cards selected for this DeckCard"?  Or does the number relate to a particular Card?

Comment: The numberSelected is related to the number of times that card is selected for the deck and the DeckCard is related to the user has selected this particular card for this Deck. I am sorry that my relationships are confusing as I look at it now I am going to set them to differentiate from the attributes better. But the Cards is an entity that just contains the objects that can be selected by the user and then the DeckCards entity stores those selections to be recalled when the Deck is pulled up on a different tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, given the added information in the comments, that you need to revise your model slightly: each `DeckCards` object should have only one `Card` to which it relates, i.e. the `cardsselected` on the `DeckCards` entity should be "to-one".  This is because the attributes `cardsSelected` and `numberSelected` relate to one particular `Card`, not to a group of them.  And the inverse relationship (`cardselections` on the `Cards` entity) should be "to-many": each Card object can be related to many `DeckCards` objects.

Also, I think the `cardsSelected` attribute of `DeckCards` will be redundant and can be deleted: if a card is selected (for a particular Deck), there will be a `DeckCards` object related to it.  And if it is not selected, there will be no `DeckCards` object related to it.

Presumably the user selects or creates a `Deck` object, let's call it `currentDeck` and then selects the Cards from the table view to be used in that `Deck`.  In your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you create (or update) the `DeckCards` object for the chosen Card and Deck.  Not sure how you determine `numberSelected`, perhaps with an Alert Controller or a further view controller?

Something like this (by the way, note that in your code in the question you are using "did**De**selectRow..." not "didSelectRow..."):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var myDeckCard : DeckCards?
    let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Cards
    // check: is there already a DeckCards object for this Card and this Deck?
    for eachDeckCard in listed.cardselections {
        if eachDeckCard.deckcomplete == currentDeck {
            // There is already a DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
            myDeckCard = eachDeckCard
        }
    }
    if myDeckCard == nil {
        // There is no DeckCard object for this Card and currentDeck
        // So create one...
        myDeckCard = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DeckCards", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        myDeckCard.cardsselected = listed
        myDeckCard.deckcomplete = currentDeck
    }
    // your code to determine numberSelected here; I'll assume 2!
    myDeckCard.numberSelected = 2
    managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
}
```

(The above code might need a bit of tweaking to properly cast and to unwrap optionals, but I hope you get the gist).

When it comes to displaying a table view of cards selected for a given deck: `currentDeck.cardsselected` will give you the appropriate set of `DeckCards` objects.  Alternatively you could fetch `DeckCards` objects using a predicate to restrict the results to the correct `Deck`.  For each `DeckCards` object you can use `cardsselected.name` (etc) to determine the corresponding card's name (etc).

Comment: Wow that is probably the most detailed and one of the best explanations for how to do something! Thank you for that I only have one more slight thing related to this which is lets say the user wants to edit this afterwords and change the deckcard objects in a different view controller would I just open MOC on that view controller and allow the user to delete the selected object using the didselectatrow command. Is there anything else I need to be aware of when I do this as I know that MOCS in the way they relate to each view controller is unique in how the application reads the relationships.

Comment: I was also thinking of having the user tap on the cell 1 time for 1 card 2 times for 2 cards and if they tap it again it returns to one am I able to use the same didselectatrow method?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, using didSelectRow... to increment the numberSelected with each tap makes sense, looping round to zero to effectively deselect.  You should be OK to delete the DeckCards object when the user deselects, provided you don't have a strong reference to it elsewhere.  For example if you load an array with all the DeckCards objects in one VC, then segue to another where you do the delete, you need to be sure to update the array to remove the now deleted object.

Comment: Ok yea that makes sense! I am busy working through the general way you provided trying to fix type casts as well as referencing the object that is being recorded to. It is being passed from another view controller so some of the references in the code provided are slightly off but it has provided a great step in the right direction hoping that I can clear up the rest in the next few hours!

Comment: I know I already accepted the answer but I was trying to work through the code and still having some issues...I was wondering if you might help me clarify this part a little bit more as I was working through all the typecasting and the final result doesn't actually let me set the object relationship still. Is it possible to move this to a chatroom?

Comment: Sure.  Give me a few minutes and I'll set one up.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: @Matthew Might as well re-use [this one](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86547/room-for-pbasdf-and-matthew)